# How can I batch shift the creation date of files on OS X 10.6.8?

Tags: macos, date-time

Please note that I am not asking how to change the creation date of a bunch of files to a given date. I want to *shift* the date by a given amount of time, for example 47732400 seconds.

Can I accomplish this using `touch` or something else in BASH?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

touch only changes the creation time if the target modification time is before the original creation time.

```
for f in ~/Desktop/*; do
    old=$(stat -f %B -t %s "$f")
    touch -t $(date -r $(($old - 1234567)) +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) "$f"
done
```

SetFile always changes the creation time. It comes with the command line tools package that can be downloaded from Xcode's preferences or [Apple's website](http://developer.apple.com/downloads).

```
for f in ~/Desktop/*; do
    old=$(stat -f %B -t %s "$f")
    new=$(date -r $(($old + 1234567)) '+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    SetFile -d "$new" -m "$new" "$f"
done
```

`stat -f %B -t %s`: format birth time, time format seconds since epoch
`date -r`: reformat seconds since epoch
`touch -t`: change access and modification times
`SetFile -d`: change creation time

Comment: Lauri Ranta, you are a saint!

Comment: I have to admit your script doesn't work for me, *but* the most important thing is that you introduced me to SetFile and got me well on my way. I'm also don't understand the reason behind the quotes around some of the variables. Totally new to bash scripting.

Comment: Quotes to ensure it works even if your filenames have spaces in them.

Comment: Figured that out eventually, also I take back my previous comment about the script not working for me. It does. I'm not sure what I did wrong at first but it was my fault. Thanks again! I can now fix a bunch of video files which were shot on a camera with an incorrect date setting.

Comment: If somebody is looking for a Linux equivalent, here are the modified commands in the for loop: `old=$(stat -c %Y "$f")` and `touch -t $(date -d @$(($old - 47732400)) +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S) "$f"`.

Answer (score 0):

Reusing and enhancing a previous answer to shift files dates with a reference file/date (the old GoPro always reset its time to 2009..)

```
ref_file=GOPR3440.MP4
new_time_for_that_file=0327160015 #date's format: 27th March 2015, 16:00

ref_file_timestamp=`stat -f %B -t %s "$ref_file"`
new_time_timestamp=`date -j $new_time_for_that_file +%s`
time_diff=$[$new_time_timestamp - $ref_file_timestamp]

for f in *; do
    old=$(stat -f %B -t %s "$f")
    new=$(date -r $(($old + $time_diff)) '+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    SetFile -d "$new" -m "$new" "$f"
done
```